# TextView "fill_parent" does not fill the parent

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have a simple layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But my TextView is not taking all of the width even though I did fill_parent. How can I make it's with full size instead of just the size of the content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the outer `LinearLayout` to have `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content` in  the attributes `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Oh perfect! Also what is the difference between fill_parent and match_parent?

Comment: Both are same but `fill_parent` has been depreciated since API 8.